# emacs cannot display polars dataframes

Tags: unicode, utf-8, elpy

When I try to print a DataFrame in emacs (python & elpy enviroment), I get the following error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 15-27: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here is a minimal example where the error occurs:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [3, 2, 1],
})

print(df)
```

It is probably a simple encoding problem, however I have no approach how to solve it. In my init.el I have already made the following entry, but this does not lead to the desired success.

```
  (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
  (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
  (set-language-environment 'utf-8)
  (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

The same code, running in cmd results in a clean loocking tabel like this

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: The problem is apparently on the Python side. A full traceback would help identify what exactly is going wrong. Are you on Windows?

Comment: Hi tripleee, yes I am on Windows. How do I create a traceback?

Comment: Try  `(setenv "PYTHONIOENCODING" "utf-8")` in Emacs before running any Python things. I fortunately don't have access to Windows, but this is a common concern on that platform, and a very frequent FAQ. If you can use a less stifled OS, that should also be an easy fix.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, that (the setenv command) fixes the problem.